# Chrome adding artifacts to smaller sized PNGs?

Tags: google-chrome, png

Was using Photoshop's Quick Export to PNG with a 250x59px grayscale image. Chrome vs Safari vs Firefox comparison (ok nevermind about Firefox it's whack):

[image: chrome vs safari same png file comparison]

Tried searching the chromium groups for anything similar but didn't find anything specifically like this. Anyone know what's going on? Only seems to happen on smaller sized images, this same image not scaled down from 2000+ px does not show the same inner glow-y stuff.

Link to actual file:

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/haven-images/greyscale_logo_250x59.png

Comment: could you post/upload/link the real PNG file?

Comment: We saw a very similar effect in ImageMagick a few months ago. See <http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=26983&p=119362#p119362> It turned out to be due to a bug in ghostscript.  Is it possible that chrome is using ghostscript somewhere in the process?